# Uninstall Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, uninstall

I was upgrading my ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS but the power went off.  So when i restarted by laptop there was a black screen that came. Then I downloaded 12.04 from windows 7. It is rebooting from windows boot manager. Now how do i remove 11.10 ubuntu.

Comment: Did you do a clean install of 12.04 the second time around?

Comment: how did you intall 12.04 then?

Comment: i did my installation of 12.04 from windows 7. from the official site

Answer (score 1):

During the installation of 12.04 it should have an option to replace 11.10. If not just choose the advanced option and choose to install on the same partition that you installed 11.10.

However, if you installed using wubi you need to unistall 11.10 by going to Control Panel and Uninstall a program. Then scroll down until you see wubi click on it then click uninstall.

Hope this helps,

Leinardo